# Shortest path to visit all nodes in a complete directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, traveling-salesman

Note: This is almost the same questions as this: [Shortest path to visit all nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583392/shortest-path-to-visit-all-nodes)

**But I have a complete graph.**

Problem: Consider a complete undirected graph with nonnegative edge lengths. Question: Compute the shortest path that visits every node **at least once**.

***NB:*** This is NOT the TSP problem. The path does not have an ending node and the path can pass through nodes more than once.

**Other notes:**

The number of nodes is small (less than 20).

Comment: Have you tried modifying [the Held-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) to solve this?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz the algorithm requires visiting each node exactly once. My problem is more relaxed and should be easier?

Comment: Why is this tagged with "D"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem is still NP-Complete** (for decision variant), with reduction from [Hamiltonian Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem).

Given Hamiltonian Path Problem instance `G=(V,E)`, reduce it to your problem with: `G'=(V, E', w)` and path length `|V| - 1`.

Where:

```
E' = VxV
w(u,v) = 1  if (u,v) is in E
w(u,v) = 2  otherwise
```

- If there is a hamiltonian path in `G`, then there is a path in `G'` that costs `|V|` - 1.
- If there is a path in `G'` that costs `|V| - 1`, then by following these edges in `G`, we get a Hamiltonian Paht.

Thus, the above is a polynomial reduction from Hamiltonian Path Problem to this TSP variant, and since Hamiltonian Path Problem is NP-Hard, so is this problem.

Answer (score 3):

### Claim

Allowing nodes to be revisited does not make the problem substantially easier.

### Explanation

Suppose we wish to find a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) in a graph G.  We can turn this into an instance of your problem by setting the edge weights to 1 for edges in G, and edge weights to 10 for edges not in G.

We now have a complete graph H with non-negative edges.

Graph G has a Hamiltonian path if and only if we find the shortest path in H is of length n-1.

### Recommendation

Therefore your modified problem is NP-hard, so it seems unlikely that you can do better than simply adapting standard TSP techniques (such as the [Held-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) ) to solve it.