# Find the minimum cost to travel all nodes of a graph with given constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, shortest-path

So this problem was asked in a programming contest some time ago. It goes like given an undirected graph with n nodes. Starting from `node 1` and ending at `node n`, find the minimum cost to travel all the nodes. Each node can be reached multiple times. Given no self loops.
Total number of nodes is less than `20`.

Comment: That sounds like a kind of a traveling salesman problem. Technically easy to implement using recursion, but _very_ expensive to compute. Therefore you should give more details to the specific problem, otherwise this cannot be named.

Comment: @PMF I added some more info.

Comment: This is still a [TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) and without more constraints this cannot be solved efficiently.

Comment: It's called a [Spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree). Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55221/need-an-efficient-algorithm-to-visit-all-nodes-of-a-graph-revisiting-edges-and and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583392/shortest-path-to-visit-all-nodes

Comment: @JimMischel: The description doesn't sound like a spanning tree, really more like a TSP. Since visiting the same node multiple times is allowed here, the spanning tree is also a solution to TSP, but a pretty bad one.

Comment: @PMF I figured it out. We can solve it using a bitmask.

Comment: @PMF You're right. It's not a spanning tree. The other two links, though, are relevant.